# Ошибка при обработке события

Tags: java

```
package pro51;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Pro51 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frm = new JFrame("Графические компоненты");
    frm.setSize(400,300);
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setVisible(true);

    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
    frm.setLayout(fl);

    JButton bt = new JButton("Click");
    frm.add(bt);

    JTextField tf = new JTextField("", 10);
    frm.add(tf);

    JLabel lb = new JLabel("Output");
    frm.add(lb);

    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String nam = tf.getText();
        lb.setText("Ку" + nam);
        }
    });     
}

}
```

В строке

```
bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
```

Выводится сообщение:

> is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method actionPerfomed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А как у вас без импортов `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` и `java.awt.event.ActionListener` это собирается?

Comment: @Komdosh NetBeans 7.4
@Alex Chermenin виноват, не обратил внимания. Добавил импорты + модификатор `final` к `tf` и `lb`. Спасибо, всё работает